# Is it ok to qualify C functions with the `std` namespace?

Tags: c++, namespaces, std, qualified-name

When I use functions inherited from C, like the ones in `<cmath>` or `<cstdlib>`, should I qualify them as being part of the standard namespace `std::log`, or should I remain in the C-scope and use them as global functions? What about `size_t`?

Comment: Although I try to use `std::size_t` in interfaces I have to admit that in source files where I use `size_t` a lot I do tend use `using std::size_t;`.

Comment: @iammilind: Why the change in meaning to the question title?

Comment: @CharlesBailey, the question is interesting, so I changed the title to more generic text. The other way is also ok. It will be helpful while searching from google :). To Paul, just out of curiosity, I asked.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### If you use e.g. `<math.h>`

No, you shouldn't.

It is unspecified whether they are available in the namespace `std` on any particular implementation:

> `[C++11: D.5/2]:` Every C header, each of which has a name of the form `name.h`, behaves as if each name placed in the standard library namespace by the corresponding `cname` header is placed within the global namespace scope. **It is unspecified whether these names are first declared or defined within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace `std` and are then injected into the global namespace scope by explicit *using-declarations* (7.3.3).**

*However, you should not be using this header:*

> `[C++11: C.3.1/1]:` For compatibility with the Standard C library, the C++ standard library provides the 18 C headers (D.5), but **their use is deprecated in C++**.

---

### If you use e.g. `<cmath>`

Yes, you should.

It is unspecified whether they are available in the global namespace on any particular implementation:

> `[C++11: 17.6.1.2/4]:` Except as noted in Clauses 18 through 30 and Annex D, the contents of each header `cname` shall be the same as that of the corresponding header `name.h`, as specified in the C standard library (1.2) or the C Unicode TR, as appropriate, as if by inclusion. In the C++ standard library, however, the declarations (except for names which are defined as macros in C) are within namespace scope (3.3.6) of the namespace `std`. **It is unspecified whether these names are first declared within the global namespace scope and are then injected into namespace `std` by explicit *using-declarations* (7.3.3).**

Comment: Why standard has left it unspecified ? What can be the possible reason for this ?

Comment: @Destructor: I don't know really